# Get Category of the Ad from CategoryItems - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Could you please help me to get a Category name of the specific Ad (Post) from the CategoryItems table.

Ad Model:

```
public function cat()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function categoryItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CategoryItems::class);
}
```

Category Model:

```
public function ads()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
}

public function categoryItems()
{
  return $this->hasMany(CategoryItems::class);
}
```

CategoryItems Model:

```
public function cat()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function ads()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
}
```

AdsController Controller:

```
public function show($slug)
{
  $ad = Ad::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
  $cat = Category::get();

  return view('ads.show', compact('ad', 'cat'));
}
```

View:

```
<h2>{{ $ad->title }}</h2>
<div class="price">
  Price: {{ $ad->price }}
</div>
<div class="city">
  <h3>{{ $ad->city }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="cat">
  <h3>{{ $ad->categoryItems }}</h3>
</div>
<p>{{ $ad->body }}</p>
<p>Posted at: {{ $ad->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}</p>
```

What I get now in the "cat" block is:

```
[{"id":2,"category_id":5,"ad_id":4,"created_at":"2017-07-18 10:37:33","updated_at":"2017-07-18 10:37:33"}]
```

I don't get it any further...

**Update**:

Ads DB:

```
id | title | slug | body | price | city | created_at | updated_at
```

Categories DB:

```
id | title | slug | created_at | updated_at
```

CategoryItems DB:

```
id | category_id | ad_id | created_at | updated_at
```

Comment: Can you post the database columns of each Model?

Comment: Sure, added. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you have several category items per ad, so you should use a foreach. Try this and see if solves the problem:

```
@foreach ($ad->categoryItems as $ci)
    <div class="cat">
        <h3>{{ $ci->cat->title }}</h3>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And change the code of `cat()` function in ItemsCategory model to:

```
public function cat()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it throws the error - Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: What is the result of `dd($ad->categoryItems);`?

Comment: Try to change this in CategoryItems Model: `return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');`. But, anyway, the code seems to be right.

Comment: Ok, now it worked. I wonder why in such a way? :D Thank you anyway!

Comment: Maybe it is because your database table has a name that is not standard. I'll add this to the answer. I'm glad it works! :)

Comment: If this helped you, can you accept it as the correct answer? Thank you!

Comment: Laerte, could I please ask for some of your contacts so I could ask you another question?

Comment: You can send me a message in chat

Comment: Not sure how to do it : D